# Train local model with SVM instead of NN in federated learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-federated

I have a dataset with numeric features and labels. I am building a federated learning model using TensorFlow (TFF).
Basically, the model that I have is the (neural network) which is always explained in the TFF tutorials.
I want to ask if there is a chance to build another model for the local clients, such as SVM? since it suits my dataset.

My neural network:

```
def create_keras_model():
  initializer = tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()
  return tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(18,)),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(128),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, kernel_initializer= initializer),
      tf.keras.layers.Softmax(),
  ])
def model_fn():
  keras_model = create_keras_model()
  return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
      keras_model,
      input_spec=train_data[0].element_spec,
      loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFF supports a wide variety of models, including just about any model you can write in `tf.keras`.

You can also create a TFF model directly by subclassing https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/Model with the code for your forward pass. If you are interested in a more functional approach, you could also define an SVM model via TFF's FunctionalModel https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/models/FunctionalModel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still it is not clear to me! 
If I wanna build a Functional model, that is not making big difference from the Sequential model structure, right? but building an SVM model can be done by subclassing. While it is still not clear and this area is lack examples even in Tensofrlow tutorials and explanations. Could you refer to some examples, please!

Comment: This question sounds more like a TensorFlow or `tf.keras` question now, ie. something along the lines of "How do I build an SVM in TensorFlow?". I think you can find answers about this if you search.

As for the `FunctionalModel`, this is different form a `tf.keras` SequentialModel, as it's entirely a TFF construct. While I don't have research examples, you can check out the unit tests for examples of using this API (https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/main/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/models/functional_test.py).